# Which code indentation style is the de facto standard?

Tags: indentation, universal

The shop I work in uses 2-space indentation for all code (decided long, long ago), both front-end and back-end development.

It is my opinion that 4-space indentation is the de facto standard in the development world, but I have no facts, couldn't find any, and am not sure where to look.

What is the de facto standard for code indentation?

Comment: there is no defacto standard, but different style guides usually tend to agree on most cases, like the 4 spaces thing.

Comment: If you're asking for a link to statistics, your question is off-topic (request for external resource). If you're asking for people to chime in with their preferences, it's off-topic as a polling (opinion-based) question. If you're asking for a discussion, your question is off-topic as well. Can you make it a more specific question?

Comment: @KenWhite, I'm looking for an external resource to verify what I assume is correct. I looked at some of the other StackExchange communities, but I wasn't actually sure where to ask this question.

Comment: Then your question is off-topic. See the [help/on-topic], in particular the numbered list of items on that page. None of the SE sites are appropriate for asking for external resource links; that's what Google and Bing are for.

Comment: @KenWhite, I reworded my question. Hopefully it's more answerable and not off-topic, since Google failed me.

Comment: There is no *de facto standard* that applies to all languages on all platforms. It's a matter of personal opinion or company policy (if there's even a standard in place). That would make your current form of the question opinion-based, and still off-topic. In fact, it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/268538/62576), which was closed as being opinion based (not constructive at the time, but they have the same definition - the reason was renamed a while back).

Comment: Since there are thousands and thousands of public code repositories to analyze, I don't understand how I'm asking an opinion-based question (unless I'm misusing "de facto"). There's an answer that can be found on which indentation is most popular, which I believe would make it the "de facto" standard.

Comment: @Asuza - Ken explained, succinctly, why this is off-topic. There's no de facto standard. Use whatever looks good for you. Adjust your editor to insert the right amount of spaces (or tabs; again, no de facto standard). Just scanning thousands of repo's to discover the most prevalent indent size doesn't mean it's a de facto standard. At best, you'll get opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's commonly understood that using spaces over tabs is a sort of de facto standard in most industries for cross-platform reasons. Having to deal with tab characters on top of spaces and newlines ends up introducing overhead for dealing with lots of IDEs and so forth. It's also kind of common for shops that just use one exclusive IDE for all development to stick to tabs, which allows users to alter the appearance of the tab to whatever they prefer and the code stays consistent (2-4-30 spaces doesn't matter: each indent level is one character). Lea Verou had [some thoughts](http://lea.verou.me/2012/01/why-tabs-are-clearly-superior/) on why tabs are superior. Ironically, [there seems to be some consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430806/html-indenting-standard-tab-or-two-spaces) that tabs are bad for markup languages.

That being said, in the realm of just 2-4 spaces for indentation, the answer seems to be this: if you use graphical IDEs (intelliJ/eclipse/textmate/sublimetext), the standard is often 4 spaces. If you use command-line (vim/emacs/nano) the standard is often 2 spaces. There are a variety of compelling reasons for both, but there are some concepts that contribute to this. Horizontal space is often at a premium in console environments, especially in environments that are prone to splitting views with screen/tmux etc, but more commonly it's been found that horizontal space is a larger concern.

A lot of people are hating on this question because it's potentially off-topic, but there are actual quantifiable definitions of the definition of a de facto standard if you look through a variety of code-bases in github (or whatever environment is relevant to your industry) and see what is standard in your environment. That being said, there are lots of thoughts on this topic currently, and a lot already in the [stackexchange community](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaces-what-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e).